# MySQL - query for last created table

Tags: mysql

Is there a query that will show the last created table in a database?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Across all databases within your MySQL instance:

```
SELECT *
  FROM information_schema.TABLES
 ORDER BY CREATE_TIME DESC
 LIMIT 1
```

For the specific database you're connected to:

```
SELECT *
  FROM information_schema.TABLES
 WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = SCHEMA()
 ORDER BY CREATE_TIME DESC
 LIMIT 1
```

Comment: MySql doesn't have information_schema.TABLES available in all versions

Comment: Your MySQL might not, but mine does, and it's in the docs... http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-schema.html

Comment: @Langdon: yup. you can akso use the `SCHEMA()` function to get the name of the current database, so `WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = SCHEMA()`. 

@Rowland Shaw, this feature is supported since MySQL 5.0, generally available as of 19 october 2005