# Select last created table with sqlite3 python

Tags: sql, python-3.x, sqlite

I found a way to do it like this:

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect(
        'avg_prices.db',
        detect_types=sqlite3.PARSE_DECLTYPES | sqlite3.PARSE_COLNAMES)
cursorObj = conn.cursor()
cursorObj.execute('SELECT name from sqlite_master where type= "table"')
listed_tables =cursorObj.fetchall()
last_table = listed_tables[len(listed_tables)-1][0]

rate="VES/COP"
sql = "SELECT * FROM" + "'" + last_table + "'" + "WHERE Rates=" + "'" + rate + "'"
cursorObj.execute(sql)
result = cursorObj.fetchone()
```

Being result the values that I wanted to get.

I check this: [MySQL - query for last created table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020514/mysql-query-for-last-created-table)
And it seems there is an easier way, but I didn't manage to get it to work on python.

Answer (score 1):

SQLite *does not* store the creation time of tables.  That means that you cannot do what you want.

The `sqlite_master` has no relevant column.  You are at your own risk if you assume that the results are returned in table creation order.